# Adding output from different rules in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
my_list([this,is,a,dog,.,what,is,your,name,?,i,simply,adore,you,!]).

count(_, [], 0) :- !.
count(X, [X|Q], N) :- !, count(X, Q, N1), N is N1+1.
count(X, [_|Q], N) :- count(X, Q, N).


number_of_sentence(N) :- my_list(L),count(.,L,N).
number_of_sentence(N) :- my_list(L),count(?,L,N).
number_of_sentence(N) :- my_list(L),count(!,L,N).
```

in the above code there are three types of sentences in the list(my_list) 1 affirmative, 1 question and 1 exclamatory and when i do this

```
?- number_of_sentence(N).
N = 1 ;
N = 1 ;
N = 1.
```

now how can i add the values in N and show "total = 3"
can any one help me please......

Comment: You can make a solution using the `count` predicate you already have. Instead of the argument `X` in `count` being a single atom, make it a list `L` instead. On each iteration with `[X|Q]`, if `X` is a member of `L`, then increment your count. Then you can call it with `count([.,?,!], L, N).`

Answer (score 1):

if your Prolog has library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) you can do

```
?- aggregate(sum(C), (my_list(L), (count(.,L,C);count(?,L,C);count(!,L,C))), N).
```

but mbratch' suggestion seems better. Another method, without count/3:

```
?- aggregate(count, E^(my_list(L), member(E, L), memberchk(E, [.,?,!])), N).
L = [this, is, a, dog, '.', what, is, your, name|...],
N = 3.
```